# Postgresql insert stored procedure error : The query does not have a destination for the returned data

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to insert data in the table brand of my postgresql database. Here the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.insert_item_brand(IN brand text) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public."item_brand" ("item_brand") 
    VALUES (brand::text)

    returning "ID_item_brand";

    COMMIT;
END;
$BODY$;
```

but when I call it I get the error:

> ERROR: The query does not have a destination for the returned data
> CONTEXT: PL / pgSQL function insert_brand_auto (text) line 3 a SQL statement
>
> SQL status: 42601

I also tried to remove the line "returning..." but not work. any advice?

Comment: remove the `returning` part. A stored procedure isn't intended to return something.

Comment: 'not work' is not an adequate description.  If you get a new error after removing `returning`, what is it?

Comment: The initial problem is that `returning "ID_item_brand"` returns something from the query and you have to return that value to a variable. When you removed that clause did you remember to include the `;` at the end of the remaining `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Solved many thanks.